# How to avoid outOfMemory Error on a bitmap without reducing the resolution

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm making this 2d TD game for android. In this game i ofc. need textures/graphics for the monsters, for the towers, etc. I have decided to keep all of the pictures, that is included in all of the units attacking cycles in one picture, and all of the the pictures, that is included in the units walking cycle in another.

The problem is that I've got a lot of different units. This results in that if I want each monster-texture to have the resolution of 100x100px, the walking bitmap will end up as a 7000x15000px picture. This ofc. crashes my application, but at the same time I need everything that is inside that picture, and I don't want to reduce the resolution. How can I use these pictures without running out of memory? Or do I need to have my graphics organized in another way - if so is, I would appreciate if you could tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using all 10000 images? The complete sprite sheet for most games generally range in the hundreds or lower thousands. In a 640x480 screen you can only put 24 different characters without overlapping, having too many different characters of that size in a single screen all moving around is probably going to be too confusing.

Some things you can do to reduce your spritesheet size is to reduce the framerate of the sprites, so that multiple consecutive game frames will be rendered using the same sprite images. Many older games uses [6-8 frames](http://www.yarrninja.com/pixeltutorial/chapter15.htm) for run cycles and they look great. Simpler creeps can even cut more and only uses 3-4 images.

Another thing you can do is a smarter character and level design so that you don't actually need all characters at the same time. Put each different character is in their own file and you can load them depending on what you need for a particular level. You can also reuse sprites with different colors to indicate stronger version of another sprite, the recolored sprite do not actually exist in the spritesheet as separate character, instead it is composed at runtime. If your characters have visible equipments, you also don't need to have a sprite for every combination, instead compose the equipment sprites into the character images at runtime.

You can also reduce the color depth of your sprites, mosts handsets supports rendering RGB565 pixel format, and in many cases using the full RGB888 is probably more color than you actually needed.

Also, you should use a lower resolution images for lower DPI handsets (which are generally lower powered as well). In those handsets your 100x100 sprites would look grossly oversized.

Also, you probably don't need 100x100 pixels sized sprites for all objects. Many objects probably would probably be much smaller than that, and you can use a smaller-sized sprites cell size for them.

Answer (score 3):

A little calculation: Your bitmap has 7000x15000 pixels, that is 105000000 pixels. For every pixel you'll need 3 or 4 bytes (depending on whether you have transparency or not). Supposing you're using transparency, this is 4 bytes per pixel, so in total this is 420000000 bytes resp. **400 MB**.

So, you'll definitely want to reorganize your setup.

Answer (score 1):

As Lie has suggested you should structure your game properly so that you don't need to use all the resources at once. Your current memory requirement is too much. You could either use RGB565 configuration for your bitmaps or you can sub-sample the image. Just reducing the frame rate won't work as the currently memory requirement in each frame is very large. 
 For sub-sampling the image resource you can use following code sample:

```
        BitmapFactory.Options boundsOp = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        boundsOp.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile, boundsOp);
        if(boundsOp.outWidth == -1) 
        {
            Log.i("Error", "error");   
        }

        int width = boundsOp.outWidth;
        int height = boundsOp.outHeight;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        int temp = Math.max(width, height);
        while(temp > MAX_WIDTH)
        {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
            temp /= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options resample = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // RGB 565 configuration
        resample.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
        resample.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        //bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile, resample);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
        bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT, true);
```

- Besides all these things you also need to recycle the bitmaps when you are
  not using them.